# Solve $p(k<125)$, $k = 200 - 5X$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A certain experiment can have two possible outcomes: "failure" or "success". It is known that the probability of success is 90%. The cost of a successful experiment is 5 euro and the cost of an unsuccessful one is 10 euro. The experiment is repeated 20 times. Let $X$ be the random variable that refers to the number of successes. The total cost $k$ of the 20 experiments can be expressed by $k = 200 − 5X$. Calculate $P(k<125)$.

I tried the following:

$$125 > 200-5X = 125-200 > -5X = \frac{-75}{-5} > X = 15 > X$$

Early on (this isn't the whole problem) I found that $p(X\ge 15) \approx 0.9888$, so I'd have to use:

$$P(X<15) = 1-P(X\ge15) = 1-0.9888 = 0.0112$$

However, my book says the right answer is $0.9568$, which happens to be $P(X>15)$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Yeah, you forgot to flip the inequality when going from $125-200>-5X$ to $\frac{-75}{-5}>X$.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel This may sound a bit silly but I haven't worked with inequality in a while... why am I supposed to flip the inequality at that point?

Comment: Because you divide by a negative number in this step.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel That makes sense... Thanks